# Removing strong property from recycled UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I declare a property in my viewcontroller known as:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISegmentedViewController *segmentedControl;
```

I have a tableview where I add the segmentedControl to the first cell via this:

```
self.segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, cell.frame.size.width - 20, 30);
self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = self.segment;

[cell addSubview:self.segmentedControl];
```

I only want this control in the first view, and naturally, it gets recycled as I dequeue cells. How do I remove the segmentedControl from the subsequent cells? I can't call [self.segmentedControl removeFromSuperView] as this will remove it from the first cell.

Note: I have to declare it as a property so I can reference it from the delegate method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing to do isn't to move your control by remove/add it. But to put it in a static cell.

This can be achieve easily. Just declare your cell like it :

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:... reuseIdentifier:nil
self.segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, cell.frame.size.width - 20, 30);
self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = self.segment;

[cell addSubview:self.segmentedControl];
```

The important part is to put nil to reuseIdentifier.

So the cell won't be recycled.
Moreover you can make a strong link to the cell...

Answer (score 2):

You can either make 2 kinds of prototype cells, and load the one you need depending on the `indexPath` or set the `cell.segmentedControl.hidden` property to `NO` for the first cell and to `YES` for the rest in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (indexPath.row == 0)
  [cell addSubview:self.segmentedControl];

else if(segmentedControl.superView!=nil)
  [self.segmentedControl removeFromSuperView]
```